# Cannot access AWS Lambda console with the error saying 'You do not have sufficient permission. Access denied.'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

previously I had been able to deploy my lambda functions without any problems on my own AWS account. Now, I need to deploy them on to a different AWS account where my IAM user has an AdministratorAccess permission.

I've set up a role/policies for invoking lambdas the same way I did for my account. Before I deployed my code with terraform, I checked the console page for AWS lambda , and this error pops up.

[image]

Any idea why I still don't have enough permissions to access lambda even with my AdministratorAccess policy attached to my user?. Do I still need to add more policies to my user in order to access Lambda?

Comment: can you share your policy document?

Comment: Is your AWS Account part of an AWS Organizations hierarchy? That is, does somebody else in your company manage all your AWS Accounts centrally?

Comment: @NinadGaikwad  I have an AdministratorAccess so should be able to access all the services ? 
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: @JohnRotenstein no, I'm the only one who manages the account except for the billing.

Comment: You must check your emails, any security notices in AWS Health. Your error is typical for a scenario where AWS limited usability of your account since it "thinks" it was hacked or used for malicious purposes.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same issue. You need to contact AWS to unlock your access as your account has been locked due to potentially dangerous activity.

I recommend you to enable MFA and use an IAM user to log in to AWS console instead of root user.

Answer (score 0):

`AdministratorAccess` is definitely enough to view the Lambda console.

Do you have CLI access setup for this user? You could try running the [`list-functions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/list-functions.html) CLI command to confirm that you user is setup as expected, as this uses the same API call that the web console is performing for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, after checking this post I checked my mailbox. AWS asked my to verify my account by sending utility bills picture and address information. I did it and everything is back to normal now.